# A thousand years is like one day

Tags: nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, 2-peter

### What is the Meaning of 2 Pet. 3:8 ?

2 Pet. 3:8 says, "**But, beloved, be not ignorant of this one thing, that one day is with the Lord as a thousand years, and a thousand years as one day.**"(KJV)

Can we interpret this passage to mean, 'If one day in heaven is like a thousand years on earth, did it take God seven thousand years to create earth?'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. If you haven't done so already, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://goo.gl/5U2gsX) and read up on how this site is a [little different](http://goo.gl/wCxRAv) than other sites around the web. In particular, pay attention to what constitutes a [good](http://goo.gl/yBdAcO) [question](http://goo.gl/18PZou) and make sure any qeustion you post meets those guidelines.

Comment: @WillianVictorLedger Hi, and Wecome to BHSE! I took the liberty to 're-format' your question to fit our Site Directives. You can certainly review, change, or reverse them, but as it stands it will probably be closed. You may want to review other questions as well regarding the meaning of 2 Pet.-Thank you!